# Will there be cars and airplanes in Jannah?

Tags: jannah, technology

Some people say that we wont desire or think about technology in Jannah, while others say that it will be there but far better than the worldly versions.

Comment: Did any of these people report of what they witnessed?

Answer (score 0):

Assalamu alaikum. According to my personal knowledge, in Jannah, there will be WHATEVER you desire. Whether it be cars, planes, technology etc. Its Jannah, so whatever you want will be right infront of you.

From Google:
"There is no internet in Jannah. Here is a proof of that. If there is internet in Jannah, then all the Muslims who are dead and are on facebook/Twitter/Whatsapp will be online even now. The Hadeez says, in Jannah you can have anything that you wish."

Comment: You don't go to Jannah directly when you die,  so your second statement is obsolete

Comment: Not sure if you understand how internet works... If some aliens does have "internet" in a galaxy far far away,  do you think they will be able to connect to the internet we use?

Comment: OOF sorry i copied and pasted the second part i didn't read it properly myself!